# who can read table from postgres with spark?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I want read a table from postgres with spark. I would like to do this using python.

I wrote the next code for accessing the postgres table but it doesn't seem to work:

```
a = (spark.read.format('jdbc')
         .option("url", "jdbc:postgres://localhost/datasetname")
         .option("dbtable", "tablename").option("user", "postgres")
         .option("password", "pass"))
```

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "_it dosn't work_".

Comment: as @user10465355 already mentioned please upload the error message that you get

Comment: I haven't any error. It don't do any things

Comment: @Tavakoli if you havent test it and run how do you know that it is not correct?

Comment: You could check your postgresql server-logs and reaffirm yourself that the client at least connected..

Comment: Cant you use psycopg?

Answer (score 0):

From the ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)) :

```
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

So I suppose that your error come from the fact that you use **postgres**:dbserver and not **postgresql**:dbserver !

Comment: It works with running this code in command prompt:

spark-shell --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207